# How to i make agents in AnyLogic avoid another moving agent?

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to model an agent based model where a certain agent population of people avoid to get close to a single agent, a random moving VIP.
I have tried to use`if (distanceTo(main.vip < restrictedArea)) ;moveTo(uniform(500),uniform(500))`
The agent will, most of the time, move to its new random destination through the restricted area which i want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Either you use the Material-handling library (where the transporters have build-in collision avoidance).

Or you model it youself. For that, you need a cyclic event in your agent that constantly checks the distance to whatever other agent you are interested in. If below some threshold, you tell the agent to move elsewhere.

Note: the first option can be quite slow. The second is not trivial to implement. Less due to coding skills, more because having intelligent collision avoidance algorithms is not trivial